# Handle Leak when running external commands from java

Tags: java, handle

I am noticing a handle leak with my java program when i try to execute an external process. My Sample code is provided below. Can you please guide me as to what i am doing wrong?

I am running this program using Open JDK 10 on Windows 10 OS. Is there any way to minimize the handle ?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        while (true) {
            Process p = null;
            try {
                // p = new ProcessBuilder("ipconfig").start();
                p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c ipconfig");
                BufferedReader br[] = new BufferedReader[2];
                br[1] = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
                br[0] = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

                int errCode = p.waitFor();
                try {
                    br[0].close();
                } catch (Exception a) {}
                try {
                    br[1].close();
                } catch (Exception a) {}
            } catch (Exception grrr) {}

            finally {
                try {
                    closeStreams(p);
                    p.destroy();
                } catch (Exception r) {
                }
            }
        }
    }

    static void closeStreams(Process p) throws IOException {
        p.getInputStream().close();
        p.getOutputStream().close();
        p.getErrorStream().close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you check if you see the same issue with JDK 11 or JDK 12 builds? If so, can you submit a bug?

Comment: Hi Alan, found that handles are increasing to certain level and came down lower after some time when running on another machine. Posted detailed answer. Thanks.

Comment: Error still occurs with openJDK 14

Answer (score 3):

It seems there is an issue in the Operating System(OS) or Machine where i ran the program. There is no handle leak when i ran on another machine with OpenJDK 10 but handle count increased up to max of 2800 and came down to 450.

Noticed below while experimenting.

- Using Oracle HotSpot JDK 7 & 8 ,there is no handle leak even though i close only Input & Error Stream(s) - (Not closing Output Stream since i won't use it in my code) But  the same code leaking handles when using OpenJDK 10.
- **Closing all the three Streams (Input , Output & Error) resolved the handle leak  issue**.

Comment: It took me 3 days to figure out the reason why one of my PCs had a memory/handle leak and another one did not. This was the solution. Thank you. :o